# Conditional swap of string characters in python? (Dynamic Substitution Cipher)

Tags: python, encryption, dynamic, swap, substitution

I just finished a small viginere cipher code, and I was thinking of trying to make it dynamic, by adding a swap of two characters in the sbox after each character is encrypted.

The problem is, everywhere I've seen that has some info on swapping characters in a string, the positions of the characters to be swapped have to be written out in the code itself. Is there a way to make it so the characters to be swapped are dependent on the outcome of the round of another function?

Some clarification: so at the top of my code I have:

```
a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

then in the encrypt function I have:

```
for p,k in zip(plaintext,keystream):
    pt = a.index(p)
    kt = a.index(k)
    c = pt + kt
    if c > 25:
        c -= 25
    c = a[c]
    ciphertext += c
```

So my question is, what if I wanted to swap 2 characters around in `a` after each character in the plaintext is encrypted, and have it so the characters that are swapped are dependent on the values of `a.index(p)` and `a.index(k)` for each character being encrypted? How would one go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work:

```
if not p == k:
    x, y = p, k if p < k else k, p
    a = a[:x] + a[y] + a[x+1:y] + a[x] + a[y+1:]
```

This takes everything up till the first char, then uses the other char in its place, then everything between the two chars, then replaces the second char with the first, and finally everything after the second char